# PUSH notificaciones web (firebase) | Escuchar un postMessage del ServiceWorker desde index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, push-notification, service-workers

Estoy teniendo problemas con las notificaciones push en segundo plano en la web.
Mi código es el siguiente:

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", event => {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({ type: "window", includeUncontrolled: true }).then(windowClients => {
      let appClient = null;

      for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        const client = windowClients[i];
        if (client.url.startsWith(appUrl)) {
          appClient = client;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (appClient) {
        console.log("Focus on existing client");
        appClient.focus();
        console.log('Event',event)
      }  
    })
  );
});



messaging.onBackgroundMessage(payload => {
  console.log("Recibiste mensaje mientras estabas ausente");
  console.log(payload);
  if (payload.data.type === 'push-notification') {
    self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
      clients.forEach(client => {
            client.postMessage({
              type: "push-notification",
              notificationId: payload.data.notificationId,
            });
      });
    });
  }
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: './favicon.ico', 
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Aquí envío el mensaje.
Luego en mi archivo index.js tengo lo siguiente:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const receiveMessage = (e) => {
      let dataReceived = e.data
      if (dataReceived.type == 'push-notification'){ 
        console.log('dataReceived.type == push-notification')
        dispatch(SITEACTIONS.setNotificationCard(true));
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
  }, []);




  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const hasFirebaseMessagingSupport = await isSupported();
      if (hasFirebaseMessagingSupport) {
        const { notificationForeground , serviceworkerController, requestPermission} = await import("./firebaseConfig");
        console.log('browser is supported')
        if (requestPermission()) {
          serviceworkerController()
          notificationForeground()
          
        }
      }
    })
    ();
}, []);
```

Con los mensajes en primer plano no tengo problema, se escucha el mensaje, pero no me funciona para las notificaciones en segundo plano, los console.log de firebase-messaging-sw.js se activan, me las muestra por consola a todos, pero no escucho el mensaje desde el index.js.
¿Qué debo hacer para que el postMessage del serviceWorker se escuche desde el index?

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y traduce tu pregunta al castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Si deseas publicar en inglés, puedes ir al sitio en inglés: [so]. Saludos